# How to create php blocking mechanism on concurrent requests?

Tags: php, multithreading, locking, blocking

Say I have an application recieving concurrent requests.
User A and B send requests same time, I need to process requests in a queue.

I need something like this:

```
function processRequests() {
  if(locked()) {
    wait();
  }

  $this->lock();
  ...process...
  $this->unlock();
}
```

Is there any packages or patterns helping to solve this problem?

PLEASE DON'T OFFER ANY "MESSAGE QUEUE SERVER" SOLUTIONS!

Comment: Add the request to the database (insert), have a separate process constantly checking the lowest id record which has not been processed, and process it

Comment: You would have to utilize something along the the lines of database or file locking.  Each request in PHP is executed in its own process so it is going to be difficult to have objects "checking" each other unless you serialize and persist it in some fashion.

Comment: Why you need to do this?

Comment: Do you use class ? if you use you can do this : 
`class Requests {`
 
 `private static $locked = false;`
 `static function process(){`
   `if(self::$locked==true) {`
  `/*wait();*/`
  `die('locked');//remove it`
   `}`

   `self::$locked=true;`
   `echo '..process...';`
   `//self::$locked=false;`
   
   `}`
`}`
  
  `\Requests::process();`
  `\Requests::process();`

Comment: You probably need a Semaphore - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming) http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php

Comment: Benjamin, class is used in two separate processes (different instances for each process), so your solution is not applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PHP's [Semaphore functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php), you can implement a simple locking system which will try to acquire a lock based on a key which identifies the resource you want to lock. The `sem_acquire` function will block and wait until the semaphore can be acquired:

```
$sm = sem_get(getmyinode() + hexdec(substr(md5("identifier to lock"), 24)));

if (sem_acquire($sm)) {

    ...process...

    sem_release($sm);
    sem_remove($sm);

} else {
    throw new \Exception('unable to acquire semaphore');
}
```

Comment: Even though this is mentioned in a sub page of the Semaphore functions website, it should be noted that for this to work, the SysV Semaphores need to be enabled: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php#sem.installation

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse `flock()` to make your own semaphore. The line `flock($f, LOCK_EX)` will block until another process releases the lock in `flock($f, LOCK_UN)`. More at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

```
<?php
if (! ($f = fopen('/dev/null', 'r')) )
    print('Oops, no /dev/null on this system?\n');
else {
    flock($f, LOCK_EX);
    print("I have the lock, I can do stuff now.\n");
    sleep(3);
    print("I am done, releasing.\n");
    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($f);
}
?>
```